# UDF to remove special characters, punctuation & spaces within a cell to create unique key for Vlookups

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup, excel-udf

I hacked together the following User Defined Function in VBA that allows me to remove certain non-text characters from any given Cell.

The code is as follows:

```
Function removeSpecial(sInput As String) As String
    Dim sSpecialChars As String
    Dim i As Long
    sSpecialChars = "\/:*?™""®<>|.&@#(_+`©~);-+=^$!,'" 'This is your list of characters to be removed
    For i = 1 To Len(sSpecialChars)
        sInput = Replace$(sInput, Mid$(sSpecialChars, i, 1), " ")
    Next
    removeSpecial = sInput
End Function
```

This portion of the code obviously defines what characters are to be removed:

```
sSpecialChars = "\/:*?™""®<>|.&@#(_+`©~);-+=^$!,'"
```

I also want to include a normal space character, " ", within this criteria. I was wondering if there is some sort of escape character that I can use to do this?

So, my goal is to be able to run this function, and have it remove all specified characters from a given Excel Cell, while also removing all spaces.

Also, I realize I could do this with a =SUBSTITUTE function within Excel itself, but I would like to know if it is possible in VBA.

Edit: It's fixed! Thank you simoco!

```
Function removeSpecial(sInput As String) As String
    Dim sSpecialChars As String
    Dim i As Long
    sSpecialChars = "\/:*?™""®<>|.&@# (_+`©~);-+=^$!,'" 'This is your list of characters to be removed
    For i = 1 To Len(sSpecialChars)
        sInput = Replace$(sInput, Mid$(sSpecialChars, i, 1), "") 'this will remove spaces
    Next
    removeSpecial = sInput
End Function
```

Comment: `I also want to include a normal space character` - actually it's make no sense to me. If you include space, your `Replace$` function would replace _space_ with _space_

Comment: Just use a space in the quoted text of your special characters.  No escaping is needed.

Comment: Hmm I have tried that, and my UDF still does not seem to remove space,  I will post my updated code

Comment: @AdamJ, have you seen my comment above? Your function replaces space with space. And it's expected that nothing happend (because you have third parameter of `Replace$` equals to `" "` - space, just replace it with empty string `""`)

Comment: Oh I think I see what you mean, I totally missed that in the code. Silly me. I will correct and post back when fixed. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after the advice from simoco I was able to modify my `for loop`:

```
For i = 1 To Len(sSpecialChars)
        sInput = Replace$(sInput, Mid$(sSpecialChars, i, 1), "") 'this will remove spaces
    Next
```

Now for every character in a given cell in my spreadsheet, the special characters are removed and replaced with nothing. This is essentially done by the Replace$ and Mid$ functions used together as shown:

```
sInput = Replace$(sInput, Mid$(sSpecialChars, i, 1), "") 'this will remove spaces
```

This code is executed for every single character in the cell starting with the character at position 1, via my `for loop`.

Hopefully this answer benefits someone in the future if the stumble upon my original question.